# Substr() não funciona

Tags: php, mysqli

Não consigo entender o motivo do substr não estar funcionando. Segue o código:

```
<?php

    // conexão com bd

    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $db = "loja";

    $conexao = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

    $consulta = "Select concact(substr(nome,1,10),'...') as nome from produtos";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $consulta);

    while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){

    ?>

    <p> <?php echo $linha['nome']; ?> </p>

    <?php


    }
?>
```

Comment: Qual a saída esperada e qual foi a saída obtida? Quais são os registros presentes no banco de dados?

Comment: Esperava sair, por exemplo, o nome do produto seguida de reticências após o décimo caractere (ex: Tv LCD Phi...) mas aponta o seguinte erro: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\dezembro\teste.php on line 15

Comment: Seu select está errado. Tente rodar ele direto no mysql para ver a mensagem completa, mas provavelmente concact deveria ser concat

Comment: Por favor, nas próximas vezes que perguntar não omita informações. Se deu erro, coloque **sempre** a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Caramba, nem reparei o erro. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

O erro está no comando "concact", onde o correto é "concat".

Answer (score 1):

A função `CONCAT` na sua consulta está escrita de forma errada, altere-a que irá funcionar:

```
 $consulta = "SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR(nome,1,10),'...') AS nome FROM produtos";
```